# No consigo capturar la excepción en un bucle

Tags: java, bucles, excepciones, try-catch

tengo un problema en mi código y es que tengo un menú en el que si elijo una opción 1 me lleva a un submenú en el que declaro variables de diferentes tipos. Al declarar estas variables quiero controlar que se introduzca el dato correcto y lo trato con un bloque `try-catch`.
Todo el código está dentro de un bucle `while` para ejecutarlo hasta que no selecciones salir.
Este es un codigo de prueba y resumido similar al que tengo:

```
public class Prueba_borrar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        String cadena1, cadena2;
        int numero1;
        
        while (true) {

            System.out.print("MENÚ."
                    + "\n\t1) Declarar variables"
                    + "\n\t2) Salir");

            System.out.print("\n\nSeleccione una opción: ");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            teclado.nextLine();

            if (opcion == 1) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("\nDeclaración de variables.");
                    System.out.print("\tValor variable String 1: ");
                    cadena1 = teclado.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\n\tValor variable String 2: ");
                    cadena2 = teclado.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\n\tValor variable int 1: ");
                    numero1 = teclado.nextInt();
                    teclado.nextLine();
               
                } catch (InputMismatchException error) {
                    System.out.println("El tipo de dato introducido no es válido.");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error.");
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Volviendo al menú principal.");
                }

            } else if (opcion == 2) {
                System.out.println("Programa finalizado.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al declarar las variables, si por ejemplo en la variable tipo int introduzco una cadena parece que en un principio si que me captura la excepción porque me ejecuta el bloque del catch y me vuelve a mostrar el menú, pero luego no me da la opción de volver a elegir y me salta el error en la consola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo agrega `teclado.next()` en el catch del InputMismatchException:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba{
    private static Aeropuerto listaAeropuerto[];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;
        String cadena1, cadena2;
        int numero1;
        
        while (true) {

            System.out.print("MENÚ."
                    + "\n\t1) Declarar variables"
                    + "\n\t2) Salir");

            System.out.print("\n\nSeleccione una opción: ");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            teclado.nextLine();

            if (opcion == 1) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("\nDeclaración de variables.");
                    System.out.print("\tValor variable String 1: ");
                    cadena1 = teclado.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\n\tValor variable String 2: ");
                    cadena2 = teclado.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("\n\tValor variable int 1: ");
                    numero1 = teclado.nextInt();
                    teclado.nextLine();
               
                } catch (InputMismatchException error) {
                    System.out.println("El tipo de dato introducido no es válido." + error);
                    teclado.next();
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Volviendo al menú principal.");
                }

            } else if (opcion == 2) {
                System.out.println("Programa finalizado.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sacado de: [StackOverflow Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702076/try-catch-with-inputmismatchexception-creates-infinite-loop)

Comment: He añadido la línea teclado.next(); como indicas y funciona perfectamente. Aún así no se cual es el motivo por el que hace falta, ya que en mi código añadí teclado.nextLine(); para capturar el \n tras pulsar el intro. Por qué hace falta esa linea si no vuelvo a introducir datos por teclado? Gracias.

Comment: si te soy sincero no tengo idea xDD he estado buscando explicaciones en paginas en ingles y no encontre nada